# FlatMapGroupWithState behaviour when state exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Spark group state never expires if after a new state is set (with expiration) the group gets "called" for a subsequent time before the initial expiration.

I am setting a timeout of "5 seconds" for any group state. If I send an event which creates a new state and I wait for 5 seconds the group times out successfully. However if I send an event which creates a new state and I send a similar event which also falls in the same group, this group state doesn't time out ever.

// in main class

```
val aggregation = inputStream
        .groupByKey(r => r.key)
        .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Append, GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout)(Aggregator.aggregate)
```

// in another object in another file

```
object Aggregator {
  def aggregate(key: String,
                rows: Iterator[InputSchema],
                state: GroupState[List[InputSchema]]): Iterator[InputSchema] = {

    if (state.hasTimedOut) {
      print("time out")
      val output = state.get
      state.remove()
      return output.toIterator
    }

    if (state.exists) {
      println("exists")
      state.update(state.get ++ rows.toList)
      return Iterator()
    }
    println("coming to update")
    state.update(rows.toList)
    state.setTimeoutDuration("5 seconds")
    Iterator()
  }
}
```

With the above code, the below happens

1) If i send a message where `r.key` is `12345`,

- Print message `coming to update` gets printed
- After 5 seconds `time out` gets printed.

^ Both are expected behaviour

2) If I send a message where `r.key` is `abcd` at time t1, and then I send the same message at t2 when t2-t1 is less than `5 seconds` (which is the group timeout initially set), following happens -

- Print message `coming to update` gets printed (this is for the first event at t1)
- Print message `exists` gets printed at t2
- Even after waiting for 5 seconds, the state never timesout and I don't get the `time out` print.

Expected behaviour should be that after 5 seconds from t1 the state should time out.